# Changed Java Runtime and broke Pycharm

Tags: python, java, pycharm

Prefacing by saying I know very little about this.

I tried changing the java version of pycharm to a 1.17 ?  version I downloaded, and Pycharm failed to start. I tried reinstalling pycharm, and get the following error on launch. Any help to fix my boneheaded mistake is greatly appreciated :)

Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:268)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:990)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:974)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:614)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:795)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x73f792cf) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x73f792cf
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:791)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x73f792cf) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x73f792cf
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$22(StartupUtil.java:503)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:787)
... 14 more

---

Your JRE: 17.0.1+12-LTS-39 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1

Comment: Did you changed the Java Runtime by changing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that is. I changed it by going control shift a, searching java, and changing it from there

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are running this on windows. I found the solution on macOS machines.
Essentially you have to go to yout Jetbrains folder and remove the respective pycharm chat:

```
cd ~/library
cd Application\ Support/
cd Jetbrains
ls
rm -r PyCharmCE2021.3
```

Hope you can try similar method on windows!